# Please burninate [printing]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

**[printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printing) is too broad.**

Its 11.4k questions span [HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571284/file-print-is-showing-a-blank-preview-of-webpage), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449467/how-print-a-page-without-print-preview-in-core-php-language), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567684/add-printer-via-c-sharp-on-server), [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550874/how-to-print-a-word-that-contains-more-than-6-characters), and more. Even its wiki says:

> Printing is a process for reproducing text and image, typically with
>   ink on paper using a printer.
>
> It can also refer to print text on the screen, e.g., the printf
>   function in C or the print construct in PHP.

Not only does this span multiple meanings and numerous platforms, but it also attracts off-topic questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28197161/1234256).

Comment: It is not vague, I know what it means.  Got a badge for it as well.

Comment: Tags are meant to help find questions and answers.  This one is not vague.  It is broad, but not vague.  Not all tags have to be 100% useful by themselves on an island.

Comment: I think printing is useful for the first reason and should stay.  I think printf like functions need their own tag-  text-formatting maybe?

Comment: I think it should stay for everything related to physical printing, ie. printing documents... maybe rename it to [document-printing].

Comment: There are two different meanings: I/O printing and physical document printing. Don't we already have tags for the I/O side of things?

Comment: @KevinBrown that is part of the problem, people indiscriminately use it for any kind of printing (be it paper (as the tag excerpt suggest), terminal, window, etc.)

Comment: A re-tag is probably more effective than a burnination. The tag is effective as-is, it would just be better for the more specific tags to be added on the questions where it needs. That does not warrant burninating the tag, as there is no problem with it.